# Why only the content in ListView.builder() is not scrolling?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-widget

I have a screen with Text widgets and ListView, and when I try to scroll inside the ListView, it doesn't allow me to scroll.

My body is SingleChildScrollView but that doesn't provide scrollView for the ListView.builder. I tried to wrap the ListView.build inside Expanded, but didn't work out.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("MyBar"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                "Information"),
            Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: widget.match.players.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 30.0,
                              foregroundColor: 
                                Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                              backgroundImage: 
                          CachedNetworkImageProvider("url"),
                            ),
                            title: new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Some text",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  new Text(
                                    "Some text",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ]),

                          ))
                        ],
                      );
                    }))
          ],
        )));}
  }
```

Anyone has an idea how I can make the listView.builder() scrollable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to make the `ListView.builder` not scrollable so the `SingleChildScrollView` can scroll. You could achieve that by setting one of these two properties to the `ListView.builder`:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

or

```
primary: false
```

But using the `ListView.builder` the way you're using it, it will create all the items at once. If you want to use the `ListView.builder` efficiently to create the items only when they're scrolled onto the screen, you could remove the `SingleChildScrollView` and just use `ListView.builder` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: widget.match.players.length + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return Text("Information");
    }
    int listIndex = index - 1;
    // then you could use: widget.match.players[listIndex];
    return Column(...);
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was searching for!